# What can be said about the given language?

Tags: pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

$L = \left \{ ab^{n}a^{n}|n>0 \right \} \bigcup  \left \{ aab^ka^{2k} | k>0 \right \}$

---

What can be said about the given language L ?

---

According to me, I think it is CFL and not DCFL as I tried to somehow parse it through a NPDA but not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words in the first part start with $ab$, those in the second part start with $aa$.

That should help.

Comment: Yes, thats what came in my mind first. But, I wasn't sure that am I going right .

Comment: And how do you use this, concerning your CFL vs. DCFL question?

Comment: I tried to design a PDA and this language has 2 sublanguages which will be parsed parallely, i.e, one more copy of the same PDA will be running parallely. Am I right ?

Comment: Well, I would not phrase it as two copies in parallel, but I guess that is basically OK. Two parts of the PDA for the two parts of the language. Again: what does this mean for your CFL vs. DCFL question?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. My friend gave me explaination that its a DCFL. And I was confused as i can make a PDA. Thats why, just wanted to confirm. Your comment is making me think I am missing something. Am I ?

Comment: Since both the prefixes are valid for the language they both must be distinguished and lead to accepting state this making it non-deterministic. @Garrick